# How can I calculate the median of some values with NAs in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

I would like to calculate the meidan for two categories with NA() [displayed as #N/A] in them. When I create a box plot excel is happy to help.

But when I try to work that out in a formula -- MEDIAN(N3:N2429) -- excel throws up a "value not available" error.

I could add the label for median to my box plots and manually add the figures to my table, but that's really risking me making errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`=MEDIAN(IFNA(N3:N2429, ""))` as found on the [first websearch I encountered](https://www.statology.org/excel-ignore-na/) when I looked for "excel media excluding nan".

Here is a screenshot showing that this works in a recent version of Excel on Windows:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I honestly did try googling. I was just being too specific and this didnt' come up.

Comment: This doens't actually work. If you put "" or " " as the if NA you just get a value error.

Comment: @user3009918 can you indicate what version of Excel you're using?

Comment: I'm using Excel2016

Comment: it turns out it works only if you make it an array formula. Pressing ctrl+shift+enter works. I don't understand why that works but it does.

Comment: @SaaruLindestøkke ,,, nice one + 10☺